# Replace specific values with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression, gnu

I have a file containing hundreds of values that start with `$`.

```
$ cat /tmp/file

$one $t $three
$one $t $three $t $three
```

I'm trying to use `sed` to replace only the values that start with `$t`.

```
$ sed "s/\$t/foo/g" /tmp/file

$one foo foohree
$one foo foohree foo foohree
```

But the above command replaces the `$three` values as well. How can I prevent this?

Comment: To avoid future confusion, I recommend that you use single quotes (`'`) to quote regular expressions on the command line. Typical shells turn `"\$"` (with double quotes) into the literal `$` which is a meta-character for the end-of-string in *sed* regular expressions. It just so happens that *sed* interprets it as a literal `$` if it occurs at the beginning of a regular expression literal. However, if you write `'\$'`, it becomes `\$` and *sed* will know that you want to match the literal `$` character (and not end-of-string) regardless of its position in the regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
sed "s/\$t\>/foo/g" /tmp/file
```

`\>` is a regular expression pattern match for the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below sed and awk command

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i =="$t"){gsub(/\$t/,"foo",$i)}}}1'  filename
```

sed command

```
sed "s/\$t /foo /g" filename
```

output

```
$one foo $three
$one foo $three foo $thre
```

e